# div is not being shown on form submit

Tags: javascript

When a user submits a my form i want them to see a loading message that is contained in a hidden div. Here is my form definition:

```
<form id="billingform" onsubmit="console.log('cool bean 0');alert('Form submitted!');document.getElementById['processingOveraly'].style.display = 'block'; console.log('cool bean');" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Here is the code for my div

```
<div id="processingOveraly" style="text-align:center;display:none;">
            <div class="loader">We are processing your order. This may take a few moments...</div>
        </div>
```

When the user clicks the button i can see the first `console.log` statement and `alert` statements execute. The second `console.log` statement does not execute. This tells me something is breaking at this line.

```
document.getElementById['processingOveraly'].style.display = 'block';
```

I don't see any errors in the console. What can be the issue?

Comment: Use parentheses instead of brackets `document.getElementById('processingOveraly')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to use parenthesis (`(` and `)`) instead of brackets (`[` and `]`) in `document.getElementById`.**

You did:

```
document.getElementById['processingOveraly'].style.display = 'block';
```

when it should be:

```
document.getElementById('processingOveraly').style.display = 'block';
```

This is because `documentGetElementById` is a *function*, as opposed to an *object*. Functions take parameters through parenthesis, whereas objects use brackets to return a child of the object.